# How to get static top and left position of current element react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please, help to find out.

I have a function `getCellPosition`

code is bellow:

```js
getCellPosition = (element) => {

    let coordinates = element.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let top = coordinates.top;
    let left = coordinates.left;

    //console.log(element.target)

    this.props.changePosition(top, left)

}


createCell = (k) => {

    return (

        <
        td key = {
            k
        } >
        <
        div className = "square__cell"
        onMouseOver = {
            this.getCellPosition
        } > < /div> <
        /td>
    )

}
```

```js
<button className="square__button square__button_delete square__button_row-delete"
               style={this.state.countRow===1 ||
                   this.state.mouseOnTable===false ||
                   this.state.onDelCol===true ? {visibility: "hidden"} : {visibility: "visible", top: this.state.cellTop-150}} 
                           
                           
                            <button className="square__button square__button_delete square__button_col-delete" 
               style={this.state.countCol===1 ||
                   this.state.mouseOnTable===false ||
                   this.state.onDelRow===true ? {visibility: "hidden"} : {visibility: "visible", left: this.state.cellLeft-410}}
```

in this function I took top and left coordinates from  cell

and send it to `state` with `ChangePosition` function for changing position of minus buttons. See screenshot. That is how positioning is working now.

The problem is - when I change scale the positions of minus buttons is incorrect.

How can I get some static value of this current cell?? What method should I use?

For better understanding screenshot is attached

[image]